# Can not write string into S7-1500 with Java

Tags: java, plc, siemens, apache-plc4x, plc4x

I use plc4j to read/write string from s7-1500. I can read string with statement:

```
builder.addItem("value-4.0", "%DB1.DB4.0:STRING");
```

which get string of "**hello world**" in it.
But I can not write string into the address with statement:

```
builder.addItem("value-4.0", "%DB1.DB4.0:STRING", "hello,world.");
```

And the exception is as follow:

*org.apache.commons.lang3.NotImplementedException: **Serializing STRING not implemented**
at org.apache.plc4x.java.s7.utils.StaticHelper.serializeS7String(StaticHelper.java:196)
at org.apache.plc4x.java.s7.readwrite.io.DataItemIO.staticSerialize(DataItemIO.java:418)
at org.apache.plc4x.java.s7.readwrite.io.DataItemIO.staticSerialize(DataItemIO.java:275)
at org.apache.plc4x.java.s7.readwrite.protocol.S7ProtocolLogic.serializePlcValue(S7ProtocolLogic.java:498)
at org.apache.plc4x.java.s7.readwrite.protocol.S7ProtocolLogic.write(S7ProtocolLogic.java:245)
at org.apache.plc4x.java.spi.optimizer.BaseOptimizer.lambda$optimizedWrite$2(BaseOptimizer.java:114)
at org.apache.plc4x.java.spi.optimizer.BaseOptimizer.send(BaseOptimizer.java:151)
at org.apache.plc4x.java.spi.optimizer.BaseOptimizer.optimizedWrite(BaseOptimizer.java:114)
at org.apache.plc4x.java.spi.connection.AbstractPlcConnection.write(AbstractPlcConnection.java:159)
at org.apache.plc4x.java.spi.messages.DefaultPlcWriteRequest.execute(DefaultPlcWriteRequest.java:65)*

Anybody, please give some idea. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The dependencies in pom.xml is as follow:
 `<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.plc4x</groupId>
      <artifactId>plc4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>0.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.plc4x</groupId>
      <artifactId>plc4j-driver-s7</artifactId>
      <version>0.8.0</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>`

Comment: Writing string into PLC with PLC4J is unsupported for now. You can try Snap7 with the URL http://snap7.sourceforge.net/ .

Comment: I just wanted to check this, and yes, it's true. But it shouldn't be true ... it seems I missed those 2 todo's in the code. So I'll probably implement this functionality asap and it will then be part of the 0.9.0 release.

Comment: (update) As I won't be able to implement this within a few minutes (gotta reverse engineer the correct format) I won't be able to provide a solution this weekend ... but I will make sure it's in the upcoming 0.9.0

As far as I know Moka7 (the java version of Snap7) doesn't support strings and it's GPL licensed, so depending on your use-case, I would be careful with it.